# How can I increase spotify lock screen controls duration after pause?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ipod, screen-lock, spotify

While playing Spotify on my iPod Touch I have got some controls over the player on my lock-screen.

I have to pause the player a lot and wish I could play the songs instantly after some time again. But the controls are vanishing too quickly (after couple of minutes) and I have to type login again (pressing home button twice and typing my pass-code), which is very annoying as I have to do it very often…

(*How) can I increase the time to let spotify show the controls over a longer period of time?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way of increasing the time that the controls remain on the screen for. However, there is a quicker way to be able to resume playing, You can swipe up from the bottom of the lock screen, and get access to the play / pause controller. You do not need to authenticate to do this.

Hope this helps.